# AWS EC2. Unclear packets in my system logs

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, iptables, logging

This is my first question on the serverfault. I hope this is the right place to ask a question on this topic.

I've set up an AWS EC2 Linux instance not so long ago. Today I've received email from Amazon reporting my instance network traffic usage got high last month.

I began to investigate. Being somewhat inexperienced with Linux, network and such thing I've added logging to `iptables` rules.

```
 sudo iptables -I INPUT -j LOG
 sudo iptables -I FORWARD -j LOG
 sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -j LOG
```

I know that I can not find a reason to the past excess network traffic usage but I got interesting rows in the `/var/log/messages`. This is a CentOS instance.

```
kernel: [XXXX] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=XXXX SRC=159.65.145.206 
DST=172.31.22.128 LEN=104 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=35 ID=50238 DF 
PROTO=TCP SPT=40802 DPT=22 WINDOW=157 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

I removed date, time from the log row. Also edted MAC to XXXX. But that was today. 
Linux `whois` utility tells me that source IP belongs to DigitalOcean, LLC.

Here are my thoughts about this log. As I understand it right now, there were some connection from SRC(DigitalOcean) to my AWS Linux instance. And someone or some service, connected to my instance via ssh.

Finally the question. Is it legitimate service that has connected to my instance? Maybe I should deny all network traffic except me connecting on ssh?

I need someone with more experience with AWS EC2 on this.

Comment: if you have a server with public ip and ssh listen on port 22, you will get a lot of scanner bot doing brute force

Comment: @c4f4t0r Ok got it. My console shows that packets were sent between some private range IPs. 172.31.22.128 is my private IP that AWS has assigned to me. But there are NAT in the middle of the connection. Can someone try to connect from within?

Comment: you need to check if your ec2 reside in public subnet

Comment: @c4f4t0r Yes it is.